# Regular expression for email addresses before @ symbol

Tags: php, regex

I want to a regular expression to check user email addresses first part(before @ symbol).

**Only characters numbers and "." symbol is valid.** I tried something but it is not enough.

Here is my expression but problem is user can submit multiple dots like "example..test", "ex...amp..le".

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/"
```

**Edit:** I dont want to allow underlines or something like that.

Comment: Why not hyphens? What's wrong with those? How about underscores?

Comment: did you want to allow a single dot? iF yes, then try `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/"`

Comment: You could use `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`; why roll your own in the first place? After all, an email address can only be validated if delivering an email to it succeeds (usually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your specific case

To disallow repeated characters, you can use a negative assertion:

```
if (preg_match('/(?!.*\.\.)^[a-z0-9.]+$/', $inbox_name)) {
    // valid, probably
}
```

This allows a period as the first character though, which is not allowed in an email address, so you have to refine it further:

```
if (preg_match('/(?!.*\.(\.|$))^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]*$/', $inbox_name)) {
    // valid, probably
}
```

Explanation:

1. Don't allow a period followed by another period or end of subject;
2. String must start with a letter or digit;
3. Starting character may be followed by letters, digits or periods.

#### Old answer

Use [filters](http://php.net/filter) instead of trying to roll your own email address validation:

```
var_dump(filter_var('ex..ample@example.org', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)); 
// bool(false)

var_dump(filter_var('ex.ample@example.org', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)); 
// string("ex.ample@example.org")
```

Afterwards you still have no guarantee that the email address will actually work until you attempt an email delivery (and even then it may be a false positive).

> I dont want to allow underlines or something like that.

That argument is just nonsensical; they're valid in an email address and you really have no reason to block it beyond personal preference.

Comment: I can't reach the email address second part. I am writing a web service method and it only checks first part of email address is valid or not.

Comment: @hellzone Then, just append `@example.org` before validating if you only want to validate the inbox name.

Comment: I already edited my question to show what I really want. So filters are not for me "Only characters numbers and "." symbol is valid".

Comment: @hellzone Hmm, have you tried something like `/(?!.*\.\.)^[a-z0-9.]+$/`?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$
```

You can try this.This will allow only one `.`.

```
$re = "/^(?=[^.]*\\.[^.]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/m";
$str = "asdasd.asdasd.\nasdsad.asdasd\nasdsadsad.asdasd.sa.d.";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
"/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*$/"
```

`Hyphens` and `underline` must be supported and email must first begin with an `alphanumeric character`.

Comment: Modified regexp to no longer allow double dots as in your example.

Comment: Modified it again to fix Jacks example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@/'
```

Here are some outputs:

```
$a = "sf..sf@g.com"
var_dump( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@/', $a));
int(0)
$b = "sf.sf@g.com";
var_dump( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@/', $b));
int(1)
$c = "sff.@g.com";
var_dump( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@/', $c));
int(0)
$d = "sff..@g.com";
var_dump( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@/', $d));
int(0)
$e = "adeade@g.com";
var_dump( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@/', $e));
int(1)
$f = "a.b.c@g.com";
var_dump( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@/', $f));
int(0)
```

Comment: It fails to match `"a.b.c@example.org"` though.